# Two sequence be convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]

I'm having trouble on figuring out how to show x_n and y_n are convergent.  I get that the last part is Comparison Theorem. So if i can show the two sequences are convergent I can say it's the Comparison Theorem.  I'm just not sure how to say both are convergent.

Answer (score 3):

well, $\{x_n\}$ is an increasing sequence which is bounded from above, by $y_1$ for instance (because $x_n<y_n<y_1$ because $\{y_n\}$ is decreasing), and therefore $\{x_n\}$ converges.

similarly, $\{y_n\}$ converges

Comment: Ohh i see! That makes sense.  Thanks a lot